# Take the value of the form widget in the action in Symfony1

Tags: symfony1

I used this widget plugin `sfJQueryDateTimeWidget()` in the form with widget name: desired_datetime, and i want to take its value in the action.php to save it in the database as a date formate by this `$form['desired_datetime']->getValue()`. But its take the value of the widget NULL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should be could work

```
//action
$parameter = $request->getParameter('nameform'); //recieve posted data
$form->bind($parameter); //Bind the data to the form
$object = $form->getObject(); //Get the object from the form
$d = $object->getDesiredDatetime(); //Get the value of the field


//form object
$this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('nameform[%s]');
```